# Sending form array values trought ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So my php needs 2 values, `operation => string` and `data => array`. The following is the form (**dynamically generated inputs**) :

```
<form method="post" action="/operations.php">
        Title: <input type="text" value="valuehere" name="data[title]">
                    .
                    .
                    .
        Description: <textarea name="data[description]"></textarea><br>

        <button class="btn janitor_edit" type="submit">Edit Media</button>

                    <input type="hidden" value="operateMePls" name="operation"> 
        <input type="hidden" value="254" name="data[id]">
</form>
```

And now I have to create an array from all `data[xyz]` in the form, but I'm having trouble finding a way to do so. The closest I've come to was doing like so: [link](http://hasin.me/2009/10/01/jqueryhooking-form-submit-and-making-it-an-ajax-request/)

I must store the array as key/values, no other way, so I can `ajax_request = { operation: operation_input, data : input_array_data };`.

Oh, and the form works as expected when submiting "normaly" trought POST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the form works by itself, then let jQuery take care of it [converting the data into a form suitable for XHR](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) for you.

```
data: $('#your_form').serialize();
```

Comment: If I POST this string, how do I turn it back into an array/object on the PHP side of things? Do I have to manually parse it?

Comment: @Juventus18 — You look in `$_POST`, just as you would if you submitted the form normally. The point of serialize is that it uses the standard format so you don't need to use a custom parser.

Comment: yeah, this works. Silly me, even though I "tested" this, I don't know why I thought it wouldn't work...

Answer (score 1):

I've used an object instead of an array. When you json_decode in PHP, pass "true" as your second argument, and the data will come out as an array. I think this is what you wanted. Please comment if you were looking for something different.

```
$(".janitor_edit").click(function () {
  var data = {};
  data.operation = $("input[name='operation']").val();
  data.data.id = $("input[name='data\\[id\\]']").val();
  data.data.title = $("input[name='data\\[title\\]']").val();
  data.data.description = $("input[name='data\\[description\\]']").val();
});
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the form has dynamically generated inputs, so there's no telling what will be the names of each input.

Comment: this is a good answer, but named keys arrays like array['key'] work fine in JS

Comment: dunno if can be helpful, but I did this jQuery plugin to handle dynamically generated forms, thought the right way would be using .serialize, it may help. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13443/jquery-plugin-node-tojson-convert-html-form-to-js-object#comment22176_13443

Comment: So you can do named keys. For the longest time I thought it auto cast to object because this doesn't work:  var my_array = ["key" : "value"]

I've adjusted my answer.

Comment: this links shows you're somehow right... it is possible to do var my_array; my_array['key'] = 'value'. But this is a way to 'turn an array into an object' infact the object['attribute'] = 'value' assignment is an Object feature. http://www.mojavelinux.com/articles/javascript_hashes.html